# Gridview Changes Page Title

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, gridview

Does anyone know why or how a gridview in Visual Studio would change a page title on a web page.  When the page is first opened, the title is fine.  When you start scrolling the grid, the title changes to a number that appears to be the number of pixels moved.  Numbers are 0, 14, 28, 42, etc.

I am trying to help a coworker fix the issue, but looking for a good starting point.  I've never seen this and my google searches are turning up empty.

Thanks in Advance,

Randy

Answer (score 0):

After some debugging of the code, we found that he was updating the field himself.  It was a coding error.

Thanks,

Randy